# SSIS - How to Identify which package a row in the log table is referring to?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have multiple SSIS integration packages logging to a database.  They all write to the table sysssislog.

I want a stored procedure to be able to return the success of the last run of a selected package.

How do I identify a package in sysssislog?  The executionid field would seem to work, but it seems like it's changing values on mosts runs of the same package (sometimes it stays the same).  Is there some way to know which package a log entry is coming from?

Structure of sysssislog for reference:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[sysssislog](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [event] [sysname] NOT NULL,
    [computer] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [operator] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [source] [nvarchar](1024) NOT NULL,
    [sourceid] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [executionid] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [starttime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [endtime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [datacode] [int] NOT NULL,
    [databytes] [image] NULL,
    [message] [nvarchar](2048) NOT NULL,
```

Comment: You seem to not have PackageStart and PackageEnd events enabled.

Answer (score 3):

Like the original poster, I wanted to see the name of my package in front of all of my source names when going through my SSIS log.  In reading William's response, I realized the ExecutionID could be leveraged to do exactly that, at least when using the SSIS log provider for SQL Server.

If you're using SQL Server 2008 and your SSIS logging table uses the standard name of "sysssislog", then try this query:

```
SELECT s1.id, s1.operator, s1.event, s2.source package_name, s1.source,
    CONVERT(varchar, s1.starttime, 120) AS starttime, s1.message, s1.datacode
FROM dbo.sysssislog AS s1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
       dbo.sysssislog AS s2 ON s1.executionid = s2.executionid
WHERE s2.event = 'PackageStart'
ORDER BY s1.id
```

Notes:

- The convert statement trims off the fractional seconds.
- Adjust the table name if you're using SQL Server 2005.
- I used the query to create a view I called "SSIS_Log_View"

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a nice view candidate to take a look at the history of execution of all the packages in your SSIS, you can also see how long a package was running in minutes:

```
select 
 source [PackageName], s.executionid
, min(s.starttime) StartTime
, max(s.endtime) EndTime
, (cast(max(s.endtime) as float) - cast(min(s.starttime) as float))*24*60 DurationInMinutes
from dbo.sysssislog as s
where event in ('PackageStart', 'PackageEnd')
--and source = 'foobar'
group by s.source, s.executionid
order by max(s.endtime) desc
```

Comment: Thanks, but source seems to refer to things inside my package, not the package name itself.

Comment: Also when the package errors I don't get packagestart or end events.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look if this helps you, from [Books On Line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186984.aspx)

**source nvarchar**

The name of the executable, in the package, that generated the logging entry.

**sourceid uniqueidentifier**

The GUID of the executable in the package that generated the logging entry.

Comment: source has the name of tasks run inside the package, so it doesn't seem like it would work for me.  Different packages could contain tasks with the same name, or task names inside packages could be changed.

Answer (score 1):

The column **"sourceid"** would be the same as your SSIS package GUID for the events

- PackageStart
- PackageEnd

As said above - the executionid is the guid of the particular instance of the run.

You may want to enable **"OnError"** event handler in order to produce the package that didn't fail.

To generate the report what you can do :

join msdb.[dbo].[sysdtspackages] and dbo.sysssislog table on id = sourceid. The packages that failed will have OnError entry in sysssislog table from which you can infer the status.

--
Please mark if this answers your question

Answer (score 0):

Source ID column where the event is "Package Start" identifies the package Name.  The Execution ID ties in all of the related rows for that instance of your package run.

Source ID can be tied back to your development of your package by opening your package and looking at the ID field in your package level properties.  This GUID matches your package level source ID column in the log. Each object in your package will also have its own GUID and these can be seen in the log.

Comment: I'm not seeing that.  Source contains the tasks inside the package.  Also there is no package start when my package errors.

Comment: If you are logging, the first entry you get sent to sp_ssis_addlogentry always has an event of 'Package Start'  Try running the package in BIDS and view the Log Events window to see if you have logging enabled properly.  For all of these to work, Logging must be enabled.

Comment: I do get package start but not when I hit certain errors such as a file not existing.

Comment: I have noticed that logging is sometimes flaky if you have objects under the package object with logging set to "enabled". I usually set up logging so that the pakcage has logging "enabled" and all others under have "use parent setting" set. (In the logging screen, a solid check in the checkbox is "enabled", a gray check is "use parent setting" and an empty checkbox is "disabled".)

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to monitor the execution during running the project, you will have to use a more sophisticated query like:

```
SELECT MIN(A.ID) AS ID,
 A.Source
, MIN(A.StartTime) AS StartTime
,  case when MAX(B.endtime) IS NULL then null else round((cast(MAX(B.endtime) as float) - cast(MIN(A.starttime) as float))*24*60*60, 0) end AS Seconds
, C.Message
FROM (
SELECT ID, Source, StartTime, ExecutionID
FROM SysSSiSLog
WHERE Event = 'PackageStart' 
) A
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
SELECT Source, EndTime, ExecutionID
FROM SysSSiSLog
WHERE Event = 'PackageEnd' 
) B 
ON A.Source = B.Source AND A.ExecutionID = B.ExecutionID
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
SELECT distinct Source, EndTime, ExecutionID, Message
FROM SysSSiSLog
WHERE Event = 'OnError'
) C 
ON A.Source = C.Source AND A.ExecutionID = C.ExecutionID
WHERE A.ID >= (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM SysSSiSLog WHERE Source = 'Main' AND Event = 'PackageStart')
GROUP BY A.Source, A.ExecutionID, C.Message
ORDER BY min(A.ID) Asc
```